# Laravel 5.2: Order Models by Pivot table field

Tags: php, mysql, model, eloquent, laravel-5

I have the following models:

```
- User:
id

- Product:
id
lid
user_id

- ProductCategories:
product_id
category_id
lid

- Category:
id
```

Relationships:

User hasMany Product

Product belongsToMany Category

I have a user and I have a category id and I need the products belonging to that category ordered by the lid from ProductCategory

What is the best solution for this?

Currently this is what I'm tring to use, but it does not order by the right way:

```
$products = $user->products()->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($category){
    $q->where('category_id', $category)->orderBy('product_categories.lid', 'asc');
})->paginate(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

The sollution was:

```
$products = $user->products()->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($category){
    $q->orderBy('product_categories.lid', 'asc');
})
->leftJoin('product_categories', 'products.id', '=', 'product_categories.product_id')
->leftJoin('categories', 'product_categories.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
->where('product_categories.category_id', $category)
->select('products.*')
->orderBy('product_categories.lid', 'asc')->paginate(20);
```